# Поднятие прокси на aws

Tags: docker, proxy, amazon-web-services, nat

Пытался поднять mtproto прокси на aws через docker, но к прокси так и не могу подключиться. В файрволе открыл все порты, это не помогло. Нашёл [вот такой совет](https://github.com/TelegramMessenger/MTProxy/issues/194), но docker не в курсе, что такое --nat, это какой-то устаревший параметр? Как всё-таки по-другому это настроить? Или дело вообще не в этом? Контейнер запускал такой командой 
`docker run -d -p443:666 --name=mtproto-proxy --restart=always -v proxy-config:/data telegrammessenger/proxy:latest`

Upd. Подключиться пытаюсь через телеграм, собственно это их прокси и есть, а docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
03dd91941126        telegrammessenger/proxy   "/bin/sh -c '/bin/ba…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:443->666/tcp   mtproto-proxy
```

Comment: Лобавьте в вопрос как именно вы пытаетесь подключиться к прокси и результат команды `docker ps`

Comment: добавил результаты

Comment: А mtproto какой порт должно слушать? 443? Просто у вас запросы по адресу yourAwsIp:443 перенаправляются на 666 порт внутри контейнера.

Comment: да, я знаю, делал это, чтоб посмотреть будет работать или нет, но ни тот, ни другой не отвечают

Comment: Может, проблемы с ssl сертификатом? 443 порт это же https

Comment: а как это проверить? так nat тут получается всё-таки не при чём?

Comment: ваш EC2 инстанс в публичной сети находится? К нему разрешены подключения из внешней сети вообще?